# how to use scm manager with git?

Tags: git, git-daemon

I'm just new in git and am still relying on git extension for most task.

I've search how to start git daemon in windows and found a suggestion that scm-manager may be an alternative for it.

https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/overview

I downloaded it and installed it with no problem, but I can't figure out how add my git repository into it.

I found in settings that it is located in my document and settings under the git folder, but I don't know how to configure it to make it detect a git repository.

I also added a repository under the web interface, it created a folder, but I don't know how to put a repository there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a remote repository

```
git remote add origin http://yourserver:8080/scm/git/nameofyourrepository
```

Then push it

```
git push origin master
```